# Connect OpenVPN server on Ubuntu Guest VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn

Setting up OpenVPN server on Ubuntu Server VM and trying to connect to it from HOST Windows 8 but had no luck. There is no connection. What's wrong?

Everything was done with this tutorial: http://lintut.com/install-openvpn-on-ubuntu-server/

- `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` > 1
- guest network - bridge adapter. host&guest can ping each other
- iptables

  ```
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 500 packets, 73786 bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.8.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
      0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 29 packets, 1664 bytes)
   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  ```
- `ifconfig`

  ```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:26:c7:a5  
            inet addr:10.210.0.135  Bcast:10.210.1.255  Mask:255.255.254.0

  tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
            inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
  ```

Can't understand what's wrong. Also tried to connect from another VM - the same bad luck.